# Где хранится информация о товарах?

Tags: javascript, php

Возможно глупый вопрос: Где хранится информация о товарах?
Понятно, что она из бд выводится, а потом куда к ней обращаться?
Например, В sessionStorage корзине пользователя храниться только выбранное количество и цвет, а чтобы это отобразить на странице в виде мини корзины с описанием, картинками, размером и тд, откуда всё это описание доставать? Так же из бд Ajax'ом или как?
Так же видел, что это всё в JSON файле хранили и оттуда доставали, можно так делать? И как это будет работать с большим количеством товаров?

Comment: Можно в localStorage просто хранить id товаров в БД и при переходе на станицу корзины просто обратитьcя ajax'ом к базе и достать товары с этими id

Comment: На крупных сайтах так же делается?Я думал, что это будет нагружать сервер.   И для каждого товара нужно будет отдельный запрос делать?Если нужно при каждом клике "В корзину" товар отображать

Comment: Вы можете написать API, которое примет массив из `id` и выдаст все товары по ним, но если вы экономите обращения к серверу, то можно и всю информацию о товарах в корзине хранить в localStorage примерно в таком виде, в котором они приходят с базы, благо ls предоставляет довольно большой объем пространства. В чем основная сложность?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Просто хотелось узнать, как это правильно сделать и как это работает в больших магазинах)